# as .*s does not work like gcc .*c

Tags: compiling, gcc, assembly

when i run `gcc -c *.c`, it runs:-

```
gcc -c file1.c -o file1.o
gcc -c file2.c -o file2.o
gcc -c file3.c -o file3.o
...
```

but `as *.s` runs:-

```
as file1.s -o a.out
as file2.s -o a.out
as file3.s -o a.out
...
```

by default, gcc replaces the only the file extension while compiling into an object file but gnu as sets the default file output as a.out. how to make gnu as to replace .s into .o while assembling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you can get `as` to do that on its own, but you can use `gcc` to drive `as`:

```
gcc -c *.s
```

This will produce `file1.o`, `file2.o` etc.

If you need to provide `as`-specific options, you can add them with `-Xassembler`, *e.g.*

```
gcc -c -Xassembler -mindex-reg *.s
```